# Django - Adding form to Formset and saving to dabase with Python

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

Im new at Django and Im encountered a problem. I want to add one form to formset **multiple times** and save it to database.

View:

```
sub = form['sub2'].save(commit=False)
sub.student_group = StudentGroup.objects.get(id=element)
sub.number = 2
sub.type = 'Others'
sub.student_count = secondSubgroup
sub.save()
...
detachment_formset = formset_factory(Subgroup, form=FormSubgroup, extra=0)
formset = detachment_formset(sub)
if formset.is_valid():
    for form in formset:
        if form.has_changed():
            form.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('app_student:implement'))
```

Form:

```
class FormSubgroup(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Subgroup
        exclude = ['student_group','number','type','student_count']
```

I read documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/

However , I didnt manage to do this.
As I understand formset is like a `list`, it can store many form objects and save them in *for each loop*.

Maybe I should send different params then this:

```
formset = detachment_formset(sub)
```

Should I send them one by one somehow?

```
student_group = StudentGroup.objects.get(id=element), number = 2 ...
```

Im stuck with this problem for a week please save my Life.

The main purpose is to **save subgroup form (for example) 5 times in database with different data** (changing for example just sub.number =  2,3,4....)

Comment: You haven't explained what is going wrong.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I dont know how to store and save form multiple times, i think description is more then enough to understand my problem.

Comment: It isn't, or I wouldn't have commented. **What happens** when you try the code above? What do you see? How is that different from what you are expecting to happen? What errors do you see?

Comment: Well , it doesnt work at all with `formset_factory` , i started to think that i should do something like this: store every form in a list `newList.add(sub )` BUT I got an error that says: **list doesnt have function add **(or smt similar)